# Change Background color to an element of a CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

A `CollectionView` creates `DateTime` objects through a method. I would like the element with today's `Datetime` to have a different Grid background when opening the page.

```
<CollectionView
    x:Name="ColCalendar">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray" RowSpacing="0.1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Giorno}" FontSize="8" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The only method I know of to be able to change the background is the `GestureRecognizer` but it requires the user to press the button, instead I would like it to be automatic

Comment: use an IValueConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

in your page (see docs for complete example)

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DateColorConverter x:Key="DateColor" />
     </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

...

<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding DateField,Converter={StaticResource DateColor}}" RowSpacing="0.1">
```

then create a ValueConveter class

```
public class DateColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ( ((DateTime)value).Today == DateTime.Today) return Color.Blue;
        return Color.Yellow;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not accept the word local, I assume I will have to enter a namespace, correct?

Comment: yes.  As I noted, "see docs for complete example"

Comment: Ok I solved it, but one thing is not clear to me. in the Binding I have to insert the word DataField? Or should I replace it? Why that doesn't work

Comment: "DateField" is whatever property on your model that contains the Date you want to test